# If A'B = BA, is A symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra

When A'B = BA and A is a squared matrix and B is not a zero matrix, can we say A is always symmetric?

I'm using ARPACK which is a famous eigenvalue solver software, the DSAUPD function of ARPACK says

```
c. This method has been designed to compute approximations to a 
c  few eigenpairs of a linear operator OP that is real and symmetric 
c  with respect to a real positive semi-definite symmetric matrix B, 
c  i.e.
c                   
c       B*OP = (OP')*B.
```

The reason why I'm asking that I'm wondering the `OP` in this doc must be symmetric or not in the context.

Ref: https://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/UG/node136.html#SECTION001210000000000000000

Comment: What if $B=0$? ${}{}$

Comment: This is true if $B$ is nonzero and $2\times2$, but in general false otherwise. It should be easy to cook up a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you I updated my question.

Comment: (I reopened because the question is on-topic, even if the underlying context is not) The operator $A \to A'B-BA$, for a fixed matrix $B$, is a linear operator, from the space of all square matrices of size $n$ to itself. Taking $B$ to be of a very low rank, it should be possible to show that this linear transformation has a very low rank and therefore the kernel is of a high dimension, possibly higher than $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, which would instantly show that $A$ doesn't need to be symmetric. Maybe taking $B = E_{11}$($1$ in the first position, zero in others) alone may do this.

Comment: In short : No, I don't think $A$ needs to be symmetric if $A'B = BA$ for some matrix $B$ and if $n>2$ (note that it is true if $n=2$!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $3\times 3$ put
$$ B:=\left [\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0\end{array} \right ] \quad\mbox{and}\quad A := \left [\begin{array}{ccc}1&2&0 \\ 2&3&0 \\ 3&4&5\end{array} \right ],$$
for instance.

---

As for how I came up with it: obviously, when $B$ is the identity $A$ must be symmetric. So replace $B$ with a diagonal matrix that leaves more variables free. May replicate this idea in any dimension $n\geqslant 3$.